# Place object files in particular directory with make

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I've been looking into building cpp applications with make and looking at various sources online. While it works, I'm trying to build my object files and place those into a particular directory rather then have them go into the same src/ as my source files. Ideally, I would like them to go into the OUT_O_DIR location, but they're being generated and placed in the src/, which I don't want.

I want a structure like this:

```
.
|- Makefile
|- include/
| |- *.h
|- src/
| |- *.c
|- output/
| |- App
|- obj/
| |- *.o
```

My make version:

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

My Makefile:

```
OUT_O_DIR := $(OUT_DIR)/obj
PROJ = hello
SOURCE = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
INC = $(wildcard include/*.h)
OBJS = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
CFLAGS = -I include
CC = g++

.PHONY: directories

all :   directories $(OUT_DIR)$(PROJ)

directories:    $(OUT_DIR)

$(OUT_DIR)$(PROJ) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)

.cpp.o: $(INC)
    @echo $@    
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

clean :
    rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)

$(OUT_DIR): 
    mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The '.cpp.o' does not extend to cover multiple folders. Two options

Modify OBJS and rule to build object.

```
#OBJS = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
OBJS = $(SOURCE:src/%.cpp=$(OUT_O_DIR)/%.o)

...

#.cpp.o: $(INC)
${OUT_O_DIR}/%.o: src/%.cpp $(INC)
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Or use vpath to specify the .cpp files are in src

```
#OBJS = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
OBJS = $(SOURCE:src/%.cpp=$(OUT_O_DIR)/%.o)

vpath %.cpp src

${OUT_O_DIR}/%.o: %.cpp $(INC)
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```